# Fast Givens Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

**Q**

Given $M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}\beta & 1 \\ 1 & \alpha \end{bmatrix}$ show how to choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that $M_1 \pmb x = \begin{bmatrix}x \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $M_1 D M_1^H = D_1$ is diagonal.   ​

**A**

It's easy to show that $\alpha = -\cfrac{x_1}{x_2}$ but I'm not sure how to set up the second part...

$$
\begin{align}
D_1 = M_1 D M_1^H = \begin{bmatrix}\beta & 1 \\ 1 & \alpha\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\tilde D_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \tilde D_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\beta & 1 \\ 1 & \alpha\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

And after I multiply it out and solve for $\beta$ I get

$$
\beta = -\frac{x_1}{x_2}\frac{\tilde D_2}{\tilde D_1}
$$

Which isn't very helpful... Do I have more information about $D$ than I thought I did or where am I being shortsighted?

Comment: The only thing we know about $D$ is what you've told us, which is only that it has the form $$\begin{bmatrix}\tilde D_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \tilde D_2\end{bmatrix}$$ And we only know that because you substituted for it in a calculation without any preamble.

Comment: @PaulSinclair yeah turns out we assume $D$ is given even though there's no mention of it in the problem. Given the context, we only know $A$ which is what we're going to diagonalize using the "fast givens" so maybe I'm misunderstanding why this is useful